# Grouping then getting the sum of data in dynamic dated columns

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am currently working on a resource tracker for my company and I have each individuals capacity figure by week (weeks are in the columns and each person's information is in the row). I need to be able to sum all the time in a specific month for each job role to be able to report on.

I have currently thought about grouping the dates by selecting 4 weeks but due to my fields being dynamic and there being some 5 week months, it would not be able to accurately be able to report that months figures.

Unfortunately, you can't pivot the information due to the dates been in the columns rather than the rows.

I have yet to find any formula/code that can be used to get that information.

[image: Spreadsheet information]

In the picture, I have added the information that I would like to be able to dynamically sum. The red outlines the month and the green outlines the job role information.

So I would like to be able to sum all that information under "July" and then the same for the other months so I can give my stakeholders a monthly figure of how many days capacity there is for each person/job role in that month.

Comment: Here we go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UW6hpR24L4_FOuqNc8nW8i8d8MHC9Dulk3Bv75k9P18/edit?usp=sharing

It will be the Capacity tab. I will most likely take the information in another tab to manipulate

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: My company has locked down the sheets so I can't share. I have added a picture of the information and a little more information on what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({INDIRECT("Sheet1!B3:B"&COUNTA(Sheet1!B3:B)+2), 
 MMULT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!E2:Z), 
 "where month(Col1)+1=7 and year(Col1)=2019", 0)),
 "where Col1 is not null offset 1", 0), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 FILTER(Sheet1!A2:2, MONTH(Sheet1!A2:2)=7, YEAR(Sheet1!A2:2)=2019))))^0)}, 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, this fundamentally is what I need. I however will need to do this across all the months rather than specifically one month, then use that information to pivot off and form a graph off.

So from what you sent I changed it to count off of the Employee name.

I am just wondering if there is a solution that can be dynamic so using an example MONTH(Sheet1!A2:2)=7 the "7" can be linked to a cell as well as **"where month(Col1)+1=6**. That way it is self sustaining as I want to make sure all my team can use it and not just technical people.

I will continue to play and see

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({INDIRECT("Sheet1!B3:B"&COUNTA(Sheet1!B3:B)+2), 
 MMULT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!E2:Z), 
 "where month(Col1)+1="&A1&" and year(Col1)=2019", 0)),
 "where Col1 is not null offset 1", 0), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
 FILTER(Sheet1!A2:2, MONTH(Sheet1!A2:2)=A1, YEAR(Sheet1!A2:2)=2019))))^0)}, 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0))`

Comment: months inside QUERY starts from zero, that's why there is +1 correction.